ADODB.Command with IN operator values as parameter
I want to create similar ADODB.Recordsets multiple times, so I thought it would be a good idea to do it with a prepared ADODB.Command. My issue now is that I want to fill the element list of an IN operator via command parameter, because the number of elements may differ. I nowhere found any hint how to do that. I thought adArray would be the correct DataType to do that, but it doesn't work. I get an error "wrong datatype" in the line declaring the parameter ID_CUSTOMER. Am I completely wrong about this? How to do this? Any help appreciated...
Here is what I got now:
Function OpenStandardView(ID_Customer() As Long, NumberType As Long, Number As String) As ADODB.recordset
    Dim CMD As New ADODB.Command

    With CMD
        .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ID_CUSTOMER IN (?) AND NUMBERTYPE = ? AND NUMBER = ?"
        .Prepared = True
    
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("ID_CUSTOMER", adArray, adParamInput, , ID_Customer)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("NUMBERTYPE", adInteger, adParamInput, , NumberType)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("NUMBER", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, Number)
    End With

    With OpenStandardView
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .CacheSize = 50
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .Open CMD
    End With
End Function


There isn't anything specific in ADODB for that, but you can use any of the techniques listed in the duplicate with ADODB.

ADO.Net would let you use a table-value parameter for this. You'd still have to modify the query for it (probably use a JOIN instead), but you could send the parameter as real structured data. But I'm not sure how classic ADO can handle it (so just a comment).
